# i know i know this database term, i just can't for the life of me remember it

Tags: database, terminology

i've been trying to rack my brain for this term but I just can't think of it. The description of it is as follows...

say I have a database in which a column is the day of the week and it contains plain text days of the week (ie Monday, Tuesday etc).

in order to make this column analyzable, I want to convert each day of the week to a number (so for all entries that have Monday it would change to 1, for those that are Tuesday it would change to 2 etc).

could anyone share some knowledge on what the term is I'm talking about?

Thanks alot.

Comment: "ordinal", "enumeration", "index", "reference"?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creating a numbered list is called enumeration.

define enumeration:

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define+enumeration

and just for good measure (how it plays into set theory and combinatorics:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration

Comment: enumeration it was, thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this seems like a good candidate for an enum(Enumerations )
Also we have a ENUM datatypes available for lot of database providers.

For ex :
MySQL does support ENUM 
and 
Oracle doesn't support ENUM at all.

you can get more information on this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336997/which-database-systems-support-an-enum-data-type-which-dont) stack overflow post also.