# Database design - how to structure child with multiple parents

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Given a parent table of regions consisting of north and south, and a child table of states which are associated with the region, assume that California is both a member of region north and region south. What would be the best way to represent this relationship?

My initial idea is a 3rd table to represent the cross reference. For example:

```
Table_Region
ID     Value
1      North
2      South

Table_State
ID     Value
1      California

Table_Xref
Region_ID    State_ID
1            1
2            1
```

It seems like a waste to create the 3rd table just to represent the cross reference but it allows the state table to contain just the unique values for each state. If I added region ID to the state table I would have to repeat the values in the state table for California since it falls into both regions.

Comment: What you're proposing is the usual way of dealing with a many-to-many relationship.  Though in this particular case I'd be wondering at the usefulness of the "north/south" attribute.

Comment: I agree with Joe, that is the normal way. You could also create a Table Region Id 3 Both

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, that is the normal way to design the many-to-many relationship.

If you will have only 2 (or 4) regions, you could do avoid the `Region` table and store region as an [enumerated type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336997/1431750) in `Table_Xref` without needing a separate table for Regions. Or just store it as an int where your app/queries account for the region code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It had been a while since I saw a hierarchy where there wasn't a simple 1-1 parent child relationship and creating a separate xref table seemed odd at first.