# CakePHP 3 migration missing enum

Tags: cakephp-3.0, phinx

I have a question;

Has anyone experienced to migrate a table using CakePHP 3 Migration Tool that when a specific field is an `ENUM` data type, the migration script automatically converts it into string or text.

How can I avoid it and how can I maintain the data type from `ENUM`?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem with CakePHP 4 and MariaDB. Changing generated migration as recommended by @code-kobold worked. Applied migration on production system and database was correctly updated, enum column added and default value set for existing records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the driver in use, since `enum` is [not supported by all database systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336997/which-database-systems-support-an-enum-data-type-which-dont). For the MySQL driver, using the `enum` type will result in the appropriate DDL.

Migration class:

```
public function up()
{
    $table = $this->table('testenum');
    $table
        ->addColumn('enum_column', 'enum', [
            'values' => ['one', 'two']
        ])
        ->create();
}
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `testenum` (
  `enum_column` enum('one','two') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

In the [Phinx package](https://packagist.org/packages/robmorgan/phinx), `enum` is present only in the MysqlAdapter.